# comment pager not showing in bootsrap theme

Tags: comments

I create a new theme based on `Bootsrap` and the below template files, I limit  show comment on every page on 50 comment in edit of content type in `comment` section, I have 126 comment in one of my node form that content type, but only see 50 comment and **there is not any pager**.

My question is that how can I add comment pager in below of comment?**

**comment-wrapper.tpl.php**

```
    <div id="comments" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
      <?php if ($content['comments'] && $node->type != 'forum'): ?>
        <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
        <h2 class="title"><?php print t('Comments'); ?></h2>
        <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
      <?php if ($content['comment_form']): ?>
        <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print t('Add new comment'); ?></h2>
        <?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

and    **comment.tpl.php**

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <div class="attribution">

    <?php print $picture; ?>

    <div class="submitted">
      <p class="commenter-name">
        <?php print $author; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="comment-time">
        <?php print $created; ?>
      </p>
      <p class="comment-permalink">
        <?php print $permalink; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comment-text">
    <div class="comment-arrow"></div>

    <?php if ($new): ?>
      <span class="new"><?php print $new; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <h3<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h3>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

    <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
      <?php
        // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
        hide($content['links']);
        print render($content);
      ?>
      <?php if ($signature): ?>
      <div class="user-signature clearfix">
        <?php print $signature; ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div> <!-- /.content -->

    <?php print render($content['links']); ?>
  </div> <!-- /.comment-text -->
</div>
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [this post on putting pagers above and below comments](https://www.drupal.org/node/141381):

```
function mytemplate_comment_wrapper($content) {
  $comments_per_page = _comment_get_display_setting('comments_per_page');
  $content .= theme('pager', NULL, $comments_per_page, 0);
  return theme_comment_wrapper($content);
}
```

should render a pager for you if placed in comment-wrapper.tpl.php

Comment: I found this in my search but `_comment_get_display_setting` is for drupal 6 and 5

Comment: function bartik_preprocess_comment_wrapper(&$vars){
  $vars['content']['comments']['pager'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'pager',
  );
}

Comment: Oh right, sorry... a bit muddled today.